# Image Hover Animation with fadeIn and slideUp effect

Tags: jquery, css, animation, transition

I want to apply animation for image hover like displayed in this page:

http://demo.krownthemes.com/goodwork/our-work/portfolio-9/

I'm not sure if its jQuery effect or simply CSS transition. So how to achieve this effect? with following div structre.

```
<div class="gallery_entry">

          <a class="featured_img" href="#">
            <img src="image.jpg" />

            <div class="entry_overlay">
               <p class="title">Title Here</p>
               <span class="sub_title">caption here</span>
            </div>
          </a>


</div>
```

Here is the CSS code ...

```
.gallery_entry {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.gallery_entry .featured_img {
    display: inline-block;
}

.gallery_entry .entry_overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: So... You have not tried anything yet?

Comment: i've tried jquery animate property but not sure if slideup and fadein animation simultaneously achievable through this method.

Comment: I think this animation can be done with css3. It looks like on hover, the orange mask fades in and the text moves up a little

Comment: It's css, there is a div with position:absolute and a rgba BGcolor that changes the opacity when hover that div, also the div is positioned over the image with z-index, they are using cubic-bezier transitions to archieve that effect. 

Here is a sample code that they are using:
transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.840, 0.440, 1.000);

Comment: thnx, i'll try it and will let you know if it works.

Comment: Great! got that effect using this transition property thnx for the help :)